# Close and reopen COM port after restart

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I have got a problem, programming my arduino Mega 2560 with RAMPS 1.4 with c#;
I want to send Writeline to the Com Port, It works once, but after a restart of the app it does not work anymore. I have to restart Visual Studio at all first.enter code here

```
 using System.IO.Ports;
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    private SerialPort myport;
    public MainWindow()
    {   InitializeComponent();
        init();
        {
        }
   private void init()
    {          
        myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 57600;
        myport.PortName = "COM3";
        myport.Open();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        myport.WriteLine("G0X10");
        myport.Close();}
```

This button leads me also to a new site in a frame, (not in the code) maybe this has smth to do with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: just out of curiosity right before you close the port have you considered setting `myport = null;` looks like you are assuming the object reference would be disposed from the GC try adding that and seeing if it corrects the issue.. or if the `SerialPort` implements `IDisposible` you could just write this before you close the port `((IDisposible)myport).Dispose();`

Comment: Sometimes closing a COM port in your program does not close it immediately in the system. If you wait a couple of minutes, the COM port may be available again.

Comment: Maybe I can keep it open and just add new commands? So that it is already open when I restart the Programm and I just go on with WriteLine?